# access to hard drive on plex media server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, mount, plex

I am attempting to set up a Plex media server on my Ubuntu 15.04 system from a few external hard drives. However, the Plex system is unable to find my hard drives.

The following is shown where there should be several hard drives mounted:

[image]

(The bottom five entries on the left-hand list should be shown on the right, as those hard drives are mounted there)

I have them mounted using fstab, as many people have suggested as a solution to this problem.  Here is the `/etc/fstab` file I have at the moment:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=bb2f4416-d5a1-4d73-96f8-8640c26f1b35 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=0d7fdc6e-67eb-44c9-92e7-680f1b827942 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5F21C4CB31D3F5E2 /media/chase/TVShows4TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/77228C18001ABEC4 /media/chase/TVShows4TB_2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/56E1D96F08F91049 /media/chase/Files4TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1DDCECBF50A93D5A /media/chase/Movies4TB ntfs-3g defaults,uid=plex,gid=plex,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/126ABE4C4E6A0A52 /media/chase/1TB\040Internal\040HD auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

As you can see, I have two drives for TV show media, one for files, one for movies, and another one.  They are all similarly set up to what I had previously (that didn't work), and the `Movies4TB` hard drive has been mounted slightly differently according to a solution for this problem I have seen elsewhere.

I have looked around the web and tried many solutions, but none have worked.

- I tried adding Plex to the plugdev group.
- I tried changing the permissions of the folders.
- I tried changing the `/etc/fstab` file.

Does anyone know what I could do to get around this problem?